# How to add a role on Reaction

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to create a verifying system that gives people who react to a message a role.

I have checked multiple Youtube videos, Github Repos and Stack overflow questions, but I can't get this to work.

Here are my intents:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True 
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True

bot = Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or(
    config["prefix"]), intents=intents, help_command=None)
```

I have the proper Intents set-up in the Discord Developer Portal.

Here is the verify code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    member = get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
    print(1)
    # channel and message IDs should be integer:
    if payload.channel_id == verify_channel_id and payload.message_id == verify_message_id:
        print(2)
        if str(payload.emoji) == "✅":
            print("3.1")
            # name=verified_role_name
            role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, id=945100455678185542)
            print(role)
            print(3)
        else:
            role = get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji)
            print(role)
            print(payload.emoji)

        if role is not None:
            print(5)
            await payload.member.add_roles(role)
            print(5.1)
            print(f"Assigned {member} to {role}.")


@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    member = get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
    if payload.channel_id == verify_channel_id and payload.message_id == verify_message_id:
        if str(payload.emoji) == "✅":
            print(6)
            role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, name=verified_role_name)
        else:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji)
            print(7)

        if role is not None:
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print(f"Removed {role} from {member}.")
```

When I react to the message, this is printed to the console (b is the role I want to add):

```
1
2
3.1
b 
3
5
```

Nothing else happens. I am beyond confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FINALLY found it!!

```
role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=945100455678185542)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here:

```py
            await payload.member.add_roles(role)
```

try:

```py
            await member.add_roles(role)
```

As mentioned in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member), member objects themselves have an `add_roles` method, and `payload.member` should not be used.

Comment: I changed my code, and I got the same output, nothing happenned.

Comment: Make sure you also changed `role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, id=945100455678185542)` to use `member` and not `payload.member`

Comment: I changed it to this:

role = get(member.guild.roles, id=945100455678185542)
and
await member.add_roles(role)

Comment: Do you have the permissions to change member roles? I believe it's the `member_role` permission that the bot must have been given when joining the server.

Comment: The bot has administrator permissions (yes, I know it's bad practice)

Comment: Alright - I believe the problem is that `member.add_roles()` accepts a list of Discord Snowflakes (aka IDs), so you should be able to directly pass in `945100455678185542` to `member.add_roles()` to add the role

Comment: Once again, nothing happenned. Looking at my print commands, it seems to fail on the member.add_roles(role). I can't tell why. I passed in the id as both a string and an integer, but nothing seems to help

Comment: Are you sure the role exists? Maybe try mentioning it in a private channel on the server (Discord should let you mention a role id in place of the role name)

Comment: It exists. When I ping <@&945100455678185542>, it pings the @b role.

Comment: Again from the docs, `the added Roles must appear lower in the list of roles than the highest role of the member.` - is this true? (sorry, I'm just trying random checks to see what went wrong)

Comment: It is true, Both the Bot and I have the highest role